# image display probleme with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, configuration, vhosts

EDIT: 
Ok i found the solution.

this is my new vhost config:

```
VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName local.afric-edu.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/afric-edu/
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/errors.log
 <Directory "/var/www/afric-edu">
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
AddType image/gif .gif
AddType image/ief .ief
AddType image/jpeg .jpeg .jpg .jpe
AddType image/png .png

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|css|js)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And i removed the htaccess file.

Initial Post:

i'm trying to create my theme to wordpress 3.8.1. For now, my only problem is to display images.

For example, if i set that:

```
<div style="background-image: url('images/placeholder-slide-1.jpg');" class="fullscreen-image"></div>
```

In my browser console log, i have this message:

> Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html:
>   "http://local.afric-edu.com/images/placeholder-slide-1.jpg/"

I think something is missing in my virtual host config but this is what was recommended to me on wordpress forums:

```
ServerName local.afric-edu.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/afric-edu/
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/errors.log
 <Directory "/var/www/afric-edu">
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Do you know what is missing ? And the problem is it really the vhost config ?

Thank for your help :)

Comment: Where is that image actually located? Normally when an image is uploaded it is put in a folder something like `/wp-content/uploads/YEAR/MONTH/FILENAME.JPG`

Comment: @Howlin my image is in wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/ . I tryed to set background-image: url('wp/content/themes/mytheme/images/placeholder-slide-1.jpg'): but i have a 404 error. With just images/, no 404 but this MIME problem. That's why i think it's a vhost config problem, but not sure.

Comment: The css is in a different folder than the images so it is looking for the image in `wp-content/themes/[THEMENAME]/wp/content/themes/mytheme/images/placeholder-slide-1.jpg`. Have you tried `http://DOMAINNAME.COM/wp/content/themes/mytheme/images/placeholder-slide-1.jpg` ?

Comment: @Howlin In my exemple, the style is directly in the html element (it's very bad, but it's for the test :D), so i don't think that is the problem. After test, your fully domain solution give a 404 error. i tried to test the same solution with just /images, and i have the mime error. "Retour à la case départ".